# Determining if a set of vectors is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

> Assume that $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb R^3$. Determine which of the following sets of vectors is linearly independent.
>
> a) $\left\{v\times w,0,v\right\}$
>
> b) $\left\{v,v\times w,v\times \left(v\times w\right)\right\}$
>
> c) $\left\{v,v+w,v+2w\right\}$
>
> d) $\left\{v+w,v-w\right\}$
>
> e) $\left\{v\times w,2v,\:w\times v\right\}$
>
> f) $\left\{v\times w,\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\\ 3\end{pmatrix},v,w\right\}$

I am not entirely sure how to approach this problem. My intuition is telling me that $a$ is dependent because of the zero vector, $c$ is dependent because one row is a multiple of a another row, and I thought $f$ was dependent because $v$ and $w$ are vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ whereas that set has $4$ vectors.

But I know that I am supposed to find whether or not there is a non-trivial linear combination of vectors that equals zero. But I am not sure how to do that in this case as no numbers are have been provided.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: So many questions! What did you try so far? a) is really for you!

Comment: You're right about (a) and (f), and while your conclusion is correct about (c), I don't see how "one row is a multiple of another".

Comment: That statement, if you replace "row" with "vector", does apply to another option here, namely (e).

Comment: I edited out the bold face.  Use it to highlight one key word, or maybe one sentence, or a header.  Do not write half your post in bold-face.

Comment: @likey Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that

a) is not since it contains $\vec 0$

b) $\vec v \times (\vec v \times \vec w)=\vec 0$

c) $\vec u_2-\vec u_1=\vec v+\vec w-\vec v=\vec w$ and $\vec u_3-\vec u_2=\vec w$

d) prove that $a\vec u_1+b\vec u_2=0 \iff a=b=0$

e) $\vec v \times \vec w=-\vec w \times \vec v$

f) #vectors > dimension